Find $X(j\omega)$ so that the function $g(t)=x(t)cos(2t/3)$ is an ideal lowpass filter with cutoff frequency of $\omega=2$.
This is the 4.30.b problem on page 344 of the book Signals and Systems by Oppenheim et al. $X(j\omega)$ and $G(j\omega)$ are the Fourier transform of $x(t)$ and $g(t)$, respectively.
I want to find $X(j\omega)$ so that the function $$g(t)=x(t)cos(2t/3)$$ is an ideal lowpass filter with cutoff frequency of $\omega=2$. In other words,
$$G(j\omega)=
 \begin{cases} 
      1 & |\omega|\leq 2 \\
      0 & |\omega|> 2
   \end{cases}.
$$
I already know that
$$G(j\omega)=0.5(X(j(\omega-\frac{2}{3}))+X(j(\omega+\frac{2}{3})))$$
but I cannot find $X(j\omega)$ so that it satisfies the above expression.

Use convolution of a product and the expression of $G$.

Do you mean that $X(j\omega)=G(j\omega)*(x_1(t) \times x_2(t))$, and I should find these two functions? How did you come up with such an expression?

No way. I think the problem has no solutions. It requires the right and left ends of $X(j\omega)$ be 1 and when these two ends are overlapped and added up, still be one.

Yes you got in your OP the initial step concerning the product into a sum thought the transformation. But not clear the solution exists.
